# Adding an accessory view button to the MKMapView call out annotation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, annotations, mkmapview

I've recently come across [this website](http://www.everydayone.com/2009/08/mapkit-annotation-with-buttons-example/) and I've been trying to add to my call out view a button (from a image).

The code on the websites example works just fine, but when I tried to add in the same code to my project I'm not getting the same results.

There is obviously something I've missed but I cannot seem to work this one out!

Here is my code for annotating:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;

    UIButton *advertButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    advertButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 23);
    advertButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    advertButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;

    [advertButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_right.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [advertButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showLinks:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = advertButton;

    annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
    return annView;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, The Link You Provided Is Dead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question but this was solved by setting the delegate of the MKMapView to the ViewController. Phew, took me a while to figure that out and it's so simple!!

Answer (score 15):

That guy is using a custom image to imitate the detail disclosure.  You can actually get the standard detail disclosure quite easily:

```
[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
```

Comment: Ah thanks, always useful to do thing how they are meant to be done :)

Answer (score 11):

Instead of setting the target like you did here:

```
[advertButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showLinks:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

You can use the default delegate:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```