# Add UIButton to google map markerinforwindow could not get event

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, ios6

Code:

[Add buttons to view returned by markerInfoWindow delegate method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213049/add-buttons-to-view-returned-by-markerinfowindow-delegate-method)

The `didTapWindowOfMarker` is being fired when I tap the `custom view`, but neither of the target methods for the buttons are being fired.

Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: The link you mentioned is the question itself and the answer is there on that link.Please tell what do you really want to ask?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i add a button to google maps marker info window on ios?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537206/how-can-i-add-a-button-to-google-maps-marker-info-window-on-ios)

Comment: Please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20300756/1394534