# Navigate from current location to marker

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, map-directions

Hello i have multiple markers like this:

```
var Groningen = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(...., .....)
        marker.title = "...."
        marker.icon = UIImage(named: "...")
        marker.snippet = "....."
        marker.map = mapView

var marker1= GMSMarker()
        marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(...., .....)
        marker1.title = "...."
        marker1.icon = UIImage(named: "...")
        marker1.snippet = "....."
        marker1.map = mapView
```

In want to add a button in the InfoWindow or in a label below the map that will set directions from the current location to de selected marker.

When the user click on the button its get question like this:

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapInfoWindowOfMarker marker: GMSMarker!) {

        let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Navigeer", message: "Kies een optie!", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        //Create and add the Cancel action
        let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
            //Do some stuff
        }
        actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)
        //Create and add first option action
        let GoGoogleMaps: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Google Maps", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
            if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:
                    "comgooglemaps://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14&views=traffic")!)
            } else {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:
                    "https://maps.google.com/?daddr=Amsterdam")!);

            }

            //Do some other stuff
        }
        actionSheetController.addAction(GoGoogleMaps)
        //Create and add a second option action
        let GoAppleMaps: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Apple Maps", style: .Default) { action -> Void in

            if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"http://maps.apple.com")!)) {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:
                    "http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=Amsterdam")!)
            } else {
                NSLog("Can't use Apple Maps");
            }

            //Do some other stuff
        }
        actionSheetController.addAction(GoAppleMaps)

        //We need to provide a popover sourceView when using it on iPad
       actionSheetController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender as! UIView;

        //Present the AlertController
        self.presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Is this possible in a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23198150/4195406), there is no easy way to add a touch event on a button in custom info window.

(*You could instead implement GMSMapViewDelegate's -didTapInfoWindowOfMarker: delegate method to check if the infowindow was tapped.
(the drawback is that the entire infowindow becomes one button)*)

But if you want to add an UILabel in your MapView, you need to set the `consumesGesturesInView` to be false. So the UILabel can receive touch events.

Sample Code of adding an UILabel with touch event:

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(view.frame.size.width - 100, view.frame.size.height - 40, 80, 30))
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        label.text = "direction"
        label.textAlignment = .Center
        label.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        label.clipsToBounds = true
        label.userInteractionEnabled = true

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "directionTapped")
        label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        mapView!.settings.consumesGesturesInView = false
        mapView!.addSubview(label)
        mapView!.bringSubviewToFront(label)

    }
```

Sample Code of showing Maps direction options:

```
 func directionTapped() {
        let openMapsActionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Open in Maps", message: "Choose a maps application", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
        openMapsActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Apple Maps", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.mapView!.selectedMarker.position.latitude, self.mapView!.selectedMarker.position.longitude), addressDictionary: nil)
            let item = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
            let options = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:
                MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving,
                MKLaunchOptionsShowsTrafficKey: true]
            item.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(options as [NSObject : AnyObject])
        }))
        openMapsActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Google Maps", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:
                    "comgooglemaps://?saddr=\(self.mapView!.selectedMarker.position.latitude),\(self.mapView!.selectedMarker.position.longitude)&daddr=\(self.mapView!.selectedMarker.position.latitude),\(self.mapView!.selectedMarker.position.longitude)")!)
            } else {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:
                    "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=\(self.mapView!.selectedMarker.position.latitude),\(self.mapView!.selectedMarker.position.longitude)&daddr=\(self.mapView!.selectedMarker.position.latitude),\(self.mapView!.selectedMarker.position.longitude)")!)
            }
        }))
        openMapsActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(openMapsActionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: I still have one problem can i use if else statement if the use puch the button a message will apear that the user first choose a pin then push the button