# Custom marker snippet is not calling the button action target

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift3, google-maps-markers

I've made a custom view to be shown when a user taps on marker on google map. So I've wrote the delegate method `markerInfoWindow` as:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {

        let infoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("emergencyInfo", owner: self.view, options: nil)!.first! as! emergencyInfo

        infoWindow.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 110)
        infoWindow.titleOfCenter.text = marker.title
        infoWindow.addressOfCenter.text = marker.snippet
        infoWindow.callNowButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        return infoWindow
    }
```

and `buttonTapped` fuction is implemented as

```
@objc func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        print("Yeah! Button is tapped!")
    }
```

but the problem is that it is not going inside the function.

**UPDATE**

Based on the answer I started following [this tutorial](http://kevinxh.github.io/swift/custom-and-interactive-googlemaps-ios-sdk-infowindow.html) so this is what I've implemented:

First I have declared these two variables:

```
var tappedMarker = GMSMarker()
var infoWindow = emergencyInfo(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100))
```

Then in `didTap` I did this:
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

```
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: marker.position.latitude, longitude: marker.position.longitude)

    tappedMarker = marker
    infoWindow.removeFromSuperview()
    infoWindow = emergencyInfo(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100))
    infoWindow.center = mapView.projection.point(for: location)
    infoWindow.callNowButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside) //getting error on this line
    self.view.addSubview(infoWindow)

    return false
}
```

And finally I change the `markerInfoWindow` method to:

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
        return UIView()
}
```

Now when I run the code I get error on the line where I'm setting `#selector(buttonTapped)`

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Based on some research I found that this error is occuring for the left hand side i.e. `infoWindow.callNowButton` because I have a label `infoWindow.titleOfCenter.text` for which I've just given `"Title"` at the moment and it crashes with the same error on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I was doing wrong. I was not initializing the UIView Class with xib file. So I added:

```
 class func instanceFromNib() -> emergencyInfo {
        return UINib(nibName: "emergencyInfo", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! emergencyInfo
    }
```

and instead of `infoWindow = emergencyInfo(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100))` I added:

```
infoWindow = EmergencyViewController.instanceFromNib()
```

inside `func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {` function.

And Glenn answer was also right up to some extent.

Comment: Salam @ChaudhryTalha my custominfomarker center point  gone wrong position. i.e when i tap the marker the custominformarker not show correct position on top center on marker. If you any idea about it please share.

Answer (score 4):

Nikhil is correct. However, indeed there's a sweet workaround for this that requires a little bit of effort and changes.

Before we proceed to the workaround, read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15281141/3231194:

> Possibly, as mentioned officially in documentation of Google Maps
>   Android API, the below restriction regarding infowindows applies to
>   Google Maps iOS SDK also :
>
> Info window is not a live View, rather the view is rendered as an
>   image onto the map. As a result, any listeners you set on the view are
>   disregarded and you cannot distinguish between click events on various
>   parts of the view. You are advised not to place interactive components
>   — such as buttons, checkboxes, or text inputs — within your custom
>   info window.
>
> So basically clicking on any part of the infowindow will trigger only
>   "didTapWindowOfMarker"

Then for the workaround (I've done this already and it works), you can just follow this tutorial http://kevinxh.github.io/swift/custom-and-interactive-googlemaps-ios-sdk-infowindow.html which is easy.

Bottomline is: You will need to change how you're showing your infoWindow to the map. Instead of returning your custom infoWindow in `markerInfoWindow`, you will replace that with `UIView()`.

Next is to handle the presentation (or showing) of your custom infoWindow in `didTap marker`, in there you will also handle set the selector, for example:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    guard let tappedJob = marker.userData as? Job else { return false }
    self.mapView.selectedMarker = marker

    jobInfoWindow?.buttons.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    jobInfoWindow?.job = tappedJob
    jobInfoWindow?.center = mapView.projection.point(for: marker.position)
    self.view.addSubview(jobInfoWindow!)

    return false
}
```

Comment: Kindly see my updated questions I started implementing your answer but there is an error.

Comment: Can you clean up your question and just add the whole code of your view controller? :) That would be better.

Comment: That would be a lot of code as I've a lot going on in this class. The `emergencyInfo` is a UIView class for which I've a `.xib` which I'm displaying as snippet when marker is tapped. This `.xib` has two buttons. The error is I think because the `UIView` is not yet loaded or something that is why it is saying nil.

Comment: Added a new finding in the last of my question which I found kindly see that too.

Comment: The answer is nicely put together. :)

Answer (score 1):

`GMSMarker` gets rendered as images on maps, so we are unable to get callbacks of buttons or any other UI element.

A workaround could be using `didTapWindowOfMarker`.

You can also refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15537386/6536841).

Comment: I added the method `didTapWindowOfMarker` and yes it works if I tap anywhere in the window. But if I had just one button that might've work for that, the issue is I've 2 buttons in in and both have a different method to run.

Comment: Sorry, but according to me, that will not be possible because we don't even get the location of the tap.

Comment: In my case, I had two actions, delete and edit. What I did is, I placed only edit button and then when user taps, I showed delete and edit in action sheet.

Comment: There is another workaround that I can think of. You can bring the marker to centre and show a pop up as an overlay by adding it above the `mapview` and therefore it will look like the marker has that popup. Now you are free to use as many buttons as you want. :)

Comment: Yes that would be the last option if nothing else works for me :) Thank you for your help.