# Assign action tap to google map marker, swift 2

Tags: google-maps-api-3, swift2, ios9, xcode7

I have a google map marker and i want that when i tap the marker send me to another viewController, or display a button on my map,

```
let marker1 = GMSMarker()
marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24.8236423, -107.4234671)
marker1.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
marker1.icon = UIImage(named: "flag_icon")
marker1.title = "Any title"
marker1.snippet = "Any text"
marker1.map = mapView
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved it, this is the tap function

```
    //Market Tap Function
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker!) -> Bool {
    let myFirstButton = UIButton()
    myFirstButton.setTitle("✸", forState: .Normal)
    myFirstButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
    myFirstButton.frame = CGRectMake(15, -50, 300, 500)
    myFirstButton.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(myFirstButton)
    return true
}
```

Comment: How do you call this function ?

Comment: @dipenbaks You must firsts make the Class implement GMSMapViewDelegate and than assigm mapView.delegate = self. Than the function will be called every time you press the marker like so: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16414971/774972

Answer (score 4):

You can use these steps for **swift 4 and 5**

1. implement GMSMapViewDelegate
2. punch your map to this delegate in didviewload() like this : mygooglemap.delegate = self
3. add this function to your class:

   ```
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    //do what ever you want
    return true
    }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 5+

Your Can Do This Using Delegete method

1. Assign your mapview delete to self
2. Confrim `GMSMapViewDelegate`to your self

Here is Code

`1`

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces

class HomeVC: UIViewController {
 
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     self.mapView.delegate = self
  }

}
```

`2`

```
extension HomeVC:GMSMapViewDelegate {
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        print("Do what ever you want.")
        return true
    }
}
```