# didTapInfoWindowOfMarker on iOS App Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Right now my app has multiple markers on different locations. If you tap on a marker, there is a small window popping out including a title and a snippet. I would like to implement a button in the window, or make the info window tappable, so it works as a button to execute a function. So I wrote this block in my GoogleMapsViewController.swift:

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOfMarker marker: GMSMarker) {

    print("test")
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("jobDetailVC") as! JobDetailViewController

    if let value = marker.userData as? PFObject {
        vc.name = value.objectForKey("name") as? String
        vc.descriptionF = value.objectForKey("description") as? String
        vc.price = value.objectForKey("price") as? Double
        vc.objectId = value.objectId!
    }
}
```

---

The reason why I am using: didTapInfoWindowOfMarker is because I wasn't sure how to implement it, so I read the docu from Google Maps: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p?hl=es and thought that this was the best choice.

Has anyone successfully implemented this, or something similar? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4):

You are right in using [`didTapInfoWindowOfMarker`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p.html#member-function-documentation) function to add an event in your InfoWindow.

When you're adding Map, add:

```
 mapView_.delegate=self;
```

Then use this to add the event/function of infoWindow when clicked:

```
-(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView
didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(id<GMSMarker>)marker{

   //Info window function

}
```

Example on [GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=swift&q=didTapInfoWindowOfMarker&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93):

```
// when user tap the info window of store marker, show the product list
    func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapInfoWindowOfMarker marker: GMSMarker!) {
        let storeMarker = marker as StoreMarker
        performSegueWithIdentifier("productMenu", sender: storeMarker.store)
    }
```

---

```
// when user tap the info window of store marker, pass selected store to the product list controller
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as ProductMenuController
        controller.store = sender as Store
    }
```

---

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOfMarker marker: GMSMarker) {

        for location in locations {
            let pollution = location[0]
            if pollution.locationdesc == marker.title {
                performSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifiers.locations, sender: location)
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Check this related question:

- [Adding Click Event on InfoWindow/Marker in Google Maps SDK for native iOS/objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360483/adding-click-event-on-infowindow-marker-in-google-maps-sdk-for-native-ios-object)