# Custom infobox when tap event

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to have an info box, same one as the standard for markers, to appear when a my polyline is tapped. I've gotten a `NSLog` to output when the line is tapped, but now I need to have the infobox appear instead of the `NSLog`. I've seen some Javascript examples but no objective c ones.

```
- (void)loadView {

// Create a GMSCameraPosition
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:37.551927
                                                        longitude:-77.456292
                                                             zoom:18];
GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.551709, -77.456510);
mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
self.view = mapView;
mapView.delegate = self;

GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.552243, -77.457415)];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.551054, -77.455443)];

GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];

UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self      action:@selector(labelTapped)];
tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[myLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
 myLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

polyline.spans = @[[GMSStyleSpan spanWithColor:[UIColor greenColor]]];
polyline.strokeWidth = 5.f;
polyline.tappable = true;
polyline.map = mapView;

}

- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapOverlay:(GMSOverlay *)overlay
{
    NSLog(@"in didTapOverlay");
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/events) guide from the iOS Maps tutorial.
Here's a snippet in Objective-C:

```
- (void)loadView {
  GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:1.285
                                                          longitude:103.848
                                                               zoom:12];
  GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
  mapView.delegate = self;
  self.view = mapView;
}

#pragma mark - GMSMapViewDelegate

- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView
    didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
  NSLog(@"You tapped at %f,%f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);
}
```

Here's an [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360483/adding-click-event-on-infowindow-marker-in-google-maps-sdk-for-native-ios-object) demonstrating the use of [GMSMapViewDelegate](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p):

1.conform to the GMSMapViewDelegate protocol.

```
@interface YourViewController () <GMSMapViewDelegate>
// your properties
@end
2.set your mapView_ delegate.

mapView_.delegate = self;
3.implement the GMSMapViewDelegate method

- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker {
    // your code
}
```

Addition: `marker.userData` is useful. you can set your needed data into it and use it in `- mapView:didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:`